# Is it possible to add corner radius to VictoryCandlestick?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-native

I need to do this chart:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33124078/163879536-497375de-cf3d-4c50-84ff-30b6e8ca4a5a.png

But I'm stuck on a graph like this:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33124078/163890049-74bb69c0-9753-403f-9e29-dde9ad542edc.png

Is it possible to add the circular radius to the chart with Victory?

This is my current implementation for candles:

```
<VictoryCandlestick
   candleColors={{ positive: "#EF3F23", negative: "#EF3F23" }}
   candleRatio={0.4}
   style={{ data: { strokeWidth: 0 } }}
   data={data}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under the packages/victory-native/src/components/victory-primitives/rect.js

add property in the Rect under return

```
<Rect
   vectorEffect="non-scaling-stroke"
   accessible={accessibilityLabel || undefined}
   accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
   accessibilityHint={accessibilityLabel && desc ? desc : undefined}
   {...rest}
   {...nativeStyle}
   rx=5
 />
```

hope it will work.

Comment: This property worked fine for me, however, as it inherits the style properties, I was able to add it to the VictoryCandlestick component as follows:

`<VictoryCandlestick   style={{ date: { rx: 5 } }}  />`

And I didn't need to change anything in the package.